# Rails route helpers are inexplicably prepending "postinstall" to requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000

Started GET "postinstall/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-27 07:26:15 +0000
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
```

This is basically it, all my buttons linked to helpers like:

```
new_user_registration GET      /users/sign_up(.:format)               registrations#new
edit_user_registration GET      /users/edit(.:format)                  registrations#edit
```

Only all the links are like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/postinstall/users/sign_in
```

I've been through my log and at one point requests just start being effectively poisoned by this "postinstall" business.

I've grepped for 'postinstall' because surely this word can't be coming from nowhere. I decided to sleep on it because I thought it must be a stupid mistake, but now I need help and unlike 99.9% of my previous questions - it doesn't seem this one has been answered whatsoever.

Searching for even the query "postinstall" on Google yields terrible results.

I **THINK** my problem lies in a path helper, everywhere the 'postinstall' is getting prepended to requests/urls - the path is referred to like so:

```
<a href="/users/sign_in" class="btn btn-success">Test</a>

<%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path, :class => "btn btn-success" %>
```

Where the first link would work route OK, but then the buttons to Submit the login form are trying the POST to /postinstall/users/sign_in etc... The second button would be a link to /postinstall/users etc.

I have absolutely no idea how this started, I've been over my git log and even going back 3 or 4 days (this issue started last night) the error still persists.

Is it seemingly specific to my Mac too, deployed to a dev site (Ubuntu) with no issues. I have restarted my mac etc. Any help is very obviously appreciated...

Comment: And I restarted again... and now it's working again...

Does anyone know why it was happening, I have no idea what solved it. 

I added :sessions => "users/sessions" then restarted my computer, and it worked. I then removed that line of code and restarted the server and it still works..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem.

I'm using puma as webserver, and puma uses a ENV called 'SCRIPT_NAME' which was setted with 'postinstall' value after i installed a software, doing puma inject 'postinstall' on url.

if you still having this issue, unset SCRIPT_NAME var from your ENV, using the command on shell `unset SCRIPT_NAME`.

Comment: Puma too here, I think you cracked it...

Hopefully others will find this now.

Comment: This was super useful and helpful, glad it came up on Google. Also I'd like to mention (to newbies) that if you're in another terminal window and you type `unset SCRIPT_NAME` and it returns nothing and it still has the problem. Go to the terminal window/session where you started `rails s` and do it there. Or just kill that session after you made the change in other terminal

Comment: Today is the second time that's happened to me. On both, i updated TotalTerminal, and right after this, the error occurred

Comment: Ahh I also have been updating TotalTerminal.. It happened to me again almost a week ago by the way so thanks again for the solution.

Comment: +1 @hsobral and I also updated TotalTerminal and this happened as well. Didn't put that together either.

Comment: Just happened to me AGAIN after a TotalTerminal update. I have contacted the developers of TotalTerminal and asked them to add `unset SCRIPT_NAME` to their install script. Hopefully they will do so and this issue will finally disappear.

Comment: According to the developer, this should be resolved as of TotalTerminal 1.4.11.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using TotalTerminal, the recent update leaves the SCRIPT_NAME environment variable set after the update. Rebooting the computer solves the issue.

I started a new topic on Binary Age's support site to try to get this fixed: http://discuss.binaryage.com/t/totalterminal-update-overrides-script-name-breaks-webservers/897

Comment: FYI, this bug also breaks the gunicorn web server. It fails at `path_info = path_info.split(script_name, 1)[1]` with `IndexError: list index out of range`. Mentioning it here for SEO reasons.

Comment: According to the developer, this should be resolved as of TotalTerminal 1.4.11.